# how to dereference index of pointer array of structures within a structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have global structure :

```
typedef struct node{
    int numOfOccur; 
    struct node *children; 
}Node;
Node *root;
```

then inside the other method I am doing:

```
root.numOfOccur = 0;
root.children = (Node *)calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
Node* temp = &root;
```

then I try to check in the while loop if certain index of children array is NULL or not.
I am trying to get the value in the following way

```
(temp->children)[c]
```

It says that *Statement requires expression if scalar type ('struct node' invalid)*
I tried all of the following:

```
temp -> children[c]
(*temp).children[c]
```

But neither works..

Below code does not works well.. it says "indirection requires pointer operand ('struct node' invalid).

```
*(*temp).children[c]
```

Comment: Note that `(temp->children)[c]` willn't work because `children` isn't an array but a pointer so you can accesse either `numOfOccur` or `children`, that's all the members of that struct.

Comment: @Jack well, as far as I know you can use bracket notation to access index for pointer array..

Comment: You could start with: Node *root; produces nothing but a pointer.  You also need something for it to point to, say by a Node *root = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );  There are some other problems in the code, but this is the first execution error line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code examples must be a little off.  It has to be 'Node root;' or the following code would all fail:

```
root.numOfOccur = 0;
root.children = (Node *)calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
Node* temp = &root;
```

I'm going to assume that is the case, since you are asking questions about code that follows the above logic.  If that assumption is correct, your problem is that calloc(27,sizeof()) allocates a single block of memory that holds 27 Node objects and zeros them out.  Each of the expressions you illustrate are equal:

```
(temp->children)[c]
temp->children[c]
(*temp).children[c]
```

Each references a Node object in the array, not a Node*, so you cannot check them for null.

Without the heap allocation, you have the equivalent of:

```
Node children[27];
```

Which is a single memory block of 27 Node objects.  You access these as:

```
children[c].numOfOccurs=0;
```

Make sure you don't use an index greater than 26.

In looking for a null pointer, you are treating it as is:

```
Node *children[27];
```

This is a list of 27 Node*.  In this case, assuming they were initially zeroed out, you could search for a null pointer in the list and allocate a new Node* and assign it, so long as you did not go over children[26].

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation.
But, still, if I do *(*temp).children[c] it does not work.. it says "indirection requires pointer operand ('struct node' invalid).
How should I write it to check for null value?

Comment: children[c] is a Node structure, not a pointer to a Node structure, so it cannot be null.  What do you do when you add a new node?  Set children to point to something perhaps?  If so, you could check children[c].children != NULL.

Comment: As I understand struct node *children is an array of pointers of type struct node...no? When I use calloc it just sets 27 pointers to NULL. No??

Comment: No. struct node *children is an array of struct node, not pointers to struct node.  calloc() allocates 27 actual structs and zeros them out.  children[idx] is a struct node, not a struct node*.  To have a list of pointers, you'd need struct node **children, and calloc(27,struct node*)